# PHP mysql_real_escape_string(): Access denied for user 'www-data'@'localhost'

Tags: php, mysql, apache, function, warnings

I just uploaded my website on the production server and i get the error :

```
Warning: mysql_real_escape_string(): Access denied for user 'www-data'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in file.php on line 106

Warning: mysql_real_escape_string(): A link to the server could not be established in file.php on line 106
```

the code of the function is

```
include('./../inc/conn.php');
if(isset($_GET['query']))$q = clean($_GET['query']);
function clean($var){
    return(mysql_real_escape_string($var));
}
```

the code of inc/conn.php :

```
try {
  $dns = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydatabase';
  $user = 'root';
  $pw = 'rootpw';

  $options = array(
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND    => "SET NAMES utf8",
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
  );

  $db = new PDO( $dns, $user, $pw, $options );
} catch ( Exception $e ) {
    echo "Connection error : ", $e->getMessage();
    die();
}
```

I really don't know what is going on since i have no problem on my local dev ubuntu server. Mysql, apache and php version are the same. The only thing is i use virtual host on the apache prod server. Don't know what is going on... Is there something i missed in one of the apache or php config ?

**Edit** 
Here are my folder's rights:

```
sudo ls -l /home/user/public/domain.com/www/
total 28
drwxrwxr-x 13 user www-data 4096 Aug 22 12:30 adodb5
drwxrwxr-x  2 user www-data 4096 Aug 22 12:30 ajax
drwxrwxr-x  2 user www-data 4096 Aug 22 12:31 css
drwxrwxr-x  9 user www-data 4096 Aug 22 12:33 gfx
drwxrwxr-x  2 user www-data 4096 Aug 22 12:33 inc
drwxrwxr-x  2 user www-data 4096 Aug 22 12:34 js
```

my apache virtual host config

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  # Admin email, Server Name (domain name), and any aliases
  ServerAdmin contact@domain.com
  ServerName  www.domain.com
  ServerAlias domain.com

  # Index file and Document Root (where the public files are located)
  DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
  DocumentRoot /home/user/public/domain.com/www
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>
        <Directory /home/user/public/domain.com/www>
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
            AllowOverride None
            Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>

  # Log file locations
  LogLevel warn
  ErrorLog  /home/user/public/domain.com/log/error.log
  CustomLog /home/user/public/domain.com/log/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

**Edit 2**

Ok so the problem was i didn't have any www-data user on the mysql server. So i just added user www-data with no password and no privilege in mysql and this is working fine. I will in the future trying to use PDO quote as many mentionned.
Thanks for everyone trying to help me.

Comment: Why are you using `mysql_real_escape_string` with `PDO`?

Comment: Using root in a production server, eh?

Comment: You should have access to production server environment. Ask admin if you are privileged user.

Comment: @CathedralZealot I don't know it's the first time i configure a server myself.. I must create a new mysql user with less privileges ?

Comment: @YogeshSuthar well i heard it's better to use this function to get ride of sql injection. Should i better use htmlspecialchars ? Thought if was only a php function but now i discovered it need mysql connection

Comment: @user1502952 i'm admin on prod server

Comment: @CathedralZealot Ok i found i have to use `grant all on exampleDB.* to 'example_user' identified by 'pw';` and then use this on my connect script

Comment: This requires a valid MySQL connection to be active. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4574677/1438393) answer.

Comment: @TamereJlanik PDO handles all sql injection thing when you use prepared statement, so need to use `mysql_real_escape_string`.

Comment: @TamereJlanik I'm suspecting it's more of a folder permission issue. Are you able to change permissions on folders?

Comment: @CathedralZealot yes i can. Altought i already added in the past www-data in the website folder

Comment: @CathedralZealot updated my question so you can see folder rights nad my apache virtual host config

Comment: You can find the solution for this problem [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22728123/1078570

Answer (score -14, accepted):

> **Note that this answer is terrible and opens you up to security vulnerabilities. It is the wrong solution. Do not do this. See further down for the actual solution to the problem. The fact that this answer got accepted just means that *two* people didn't know what they were doing.**

It's because you haven't a www-data in your mysql database!

You can add the www-data user through phpmyadmin and give that user no privilege and it should work

Comment: Worst possible answer. It understands nothing about the problem and promotes a terrible solution with negative security implications. And of course it got accepted. *facepalm*

Answer (score 11):

You either use PDO or you use the mysql extension, don't use both at the same time. `mysql_real_escape_string` is a function of the mysql extension. It needs a connection to the database to function. When calling it, it tries to establish a connection if you didn't previously establish one using `mysql_connect`, guestimating the required login credentials. On your local machine, you apparently have no password protection and the account name for the MySQL user is the same as the name the web server runs under, so it happens to luckily work. On the production system the credentials are different and it can't establish a connection.

Stop using `mysql_real_escape_string` with PDO. Either use PDO's string quoting functions or, better, [use prepared and parameterized queries and `bind` your values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60496/476).

Comment: you are great. 
I have same problem, and adding a connection to mysql for `mysql_real_escape_string`solves my problem. just add `mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');` in some where your config file after normal connections. Or as i will do in near future convert all `mysql_real_escape_string´ to ´PDO::quote´ or `bind`

Comment: Be aware that that is certainly **not a solution**! Don't use `mysql_real_escape_string` if you're using PDO! Period!

Answer (score 3):

`mysql_real_escape_string` needs a valid link identifier (returned by `mysql_connect()`), see http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

> link_identifier: The MySQL connection. If the link identifier is not specified, the last link opened by `mysql_connect()` is assumed. If no such link is found, it will try to create one as if `mysql_connect()` was called with no arguments. If no connection is found or established, an E_WARNING level error is generated.

Your connection is opened by PDO, so you haven't any valid link identifier for `mysql_real_escape_string`.

Try to use `PDO::quote`

Comment: Check your local username, does it exists as an user an your mysql dev server? Do you have an user called www-data with no password on your prod server?

Comment: No it doesn't exist. I think that's why it aint working. What kind of privileges must that user have ?

Comment: It was the www-data user missing ! Now it's working. So it appears PDO use mysql_connect ?

Comment: PDO::quote() is an instance method and cannot be called statically. `Fatal error: Non-static method PDO::quote() cannot be called statically`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when trying to modify user search in Wordpress backend and the thing lacking was a proper db connection (also mysql_real_escape_string() is deprecated).
The globals are defined in wp-config.php.

This is the working function. Note the $con variable.
More explanation available [here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_real_escape_string.asp).

```
if(is_admin()) {


add_action( 'pre_user_query', 'user_search_by_email' );
  function user_search_by_email($wp_user_query) {
    if(false === strpos($wp_user_query->query_where, '@') && !empty($_GET["s"])) {
      $con = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD,DB_NAME);
      $wp_user_query->query_where = str_replace(
              "user_nicename LIKE '%".mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_GET["s"])."%'",
              "user_nicename LIKE '%".mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_GET["s"])."%' OR user_email LIKE '%".mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_GET["s"])."%'",
              $wp_user_query->query_where);
      mysqli_close($con);

    }
    return $wp_user_query;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This problem arise usually when database connections are set to mysqli,
to resolve this problem and use mysql_real_escape_string() even if mysqli is set. Just go to php.ini and find:
mysql.default_user parameter and set the value to your default user
for example : mysql.default_user = root

and restart the apache, your problem is resolved now.. enjoy