# replace mysql_real_escape_string for security purposes

Tags: mysql

I was using a [WordPress Plugin](https://github.com/ericmann/custom-permalinks/blob/master/custom-permalinks.php) That broke on update to 4.3.  The error was

```
mysql_real_escape_string(): Access denied for user
```

I found out that the error was because the mysql_real_escape_string is called from within MySQL and needs to be logged in before execution.  Solutions were to include a mysql_connect before the mysql_real_escape_string, which solved the problem.  But it seems from many of the comments, the mysql_real_escape_string an this solution should not be used for various security reasons.  But I am not sure how to change the code to PDO::quote etc as I am not really sure whats going on.  The query I am trying to change is

```
function custom_permalinks_request($query) {
    global $wpdb;
    global $_CPRegisteredURL;

    // First, search for a matching custom permalink, and if found, generate the corresponding
    // original URL

    $originalUrl = NULL;

    // Get request URI, strip parameters and s
    $url = parse_url(get_bloginfo('url'));
    $url = isset($url['path']) ? $url['path'] : '';
    $request = ltrim(substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], strlen($url)),'/');
    $request = (($pos=strpos($request, '?')) ? substr($request, 0, $pos) : $request);
    $request_noslash = preg_replace('@/+@','/', trim($request, '/'));
    if ( !$request ) return $query;
    $sql = "SELECT $wpdb->posts.ID, $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value, $wpdb->posts.post_type FROM $wpdb->posts  ".
                "LEFT JOIN $wpdb->postmeta ON ($wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->postmeta.post_id) WHERE ".
                "  meta_key = 'custom_permalink' AND ".
                "  meta_value != '' AND ".
                "  ( LOWER(meta_value) = LEFT(LOWER('".mysql_real_escape_string($request_noslash)."'), LENGTH(meta_value)) OR ".
                "    LOWER(meta_value) = LEFT(LOWER('".mysql_real_escape_string($request_noslash."/")."'), LENGTH(meta_value)) ) ".
                "ORDER BY LENGTH(meta_value) DESC LIMIT 1";
    $posts = $wpdb->get_results($sql);
return $query;
}
```

Is there an easy way to replace the mysql_real_escape_string or better way to do this?  I am not sure [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1162491/alternative-to-mysql-real-escape-string-without-connecting-to-db) is similar, but I dont see how to implement the answers.

Comment: If properly used mysql_real_escape_string is pretty secure, although now deprecated. There are complex tricks that can be done to breach it. Problem here is that I suspect your connection though the $wpdb object is not identical to the one used by mysql_real_escape_string. The connection is important to escape the data correctly, otherwise you could just use mysql_escape_string which doesn't require a connection but which is less secure.

Comment: this question made it seem pretty bad - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18378976/php-mysql-real-escape-string-access-denied-for-user-www-datalocalhost  But maybe thats becaise it is PDO, which I dont think wordpress is?  And adding a mysql_connect with all the data to the function, is safe enough?

Comment: Problem is that it is meant to be the same link as is being used by the query, not just a random link. Mysql_real_escape_string escapes things that are specific to that connection (eg, the character set used), hence using a different link can result in things being escaped incorrectly. If you are using pdo then you can pass parameters and do not concatenate in escaped strings.

Comment: mySQL is not my strength, but thanks for the help.  I understand it a bit more.